# VS Code node debug with command

Tags: node.js, debugging, command, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run through a simple CRUD node module using VS Code.

A simplified version of the module looks like this:

```
const getAll = () => {
  // return all elements
}

const saveElement = element => {
  // takes an object and goes through it and saves it
}

const removeElement = id => {
  // deletes the element with the passed id or returns false
}

const readElement = id => {
  // returns the element from the data
}
```

I'm using yargs to get the arguments for the app, but also I'm using commands to call each method, like this

```
node app.js remove --id="123456789"
```

The `launch.json` in VS Code looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [       
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Test Remove",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
      "args": [
        "--id='123456789'"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I've been unable to do is adding the specific `remove`, `add`, `list`, `read` commands into the debugger to check those methods, because without those the app runs just with the arguments and it returns a log I added indicating that the command passed is not recognized.

I looked in the VS Code docs, but I didn't found anything that relates to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok got it. It's quite simple actually. Just pass the module's specific command in the `args` array. The only caveat is that the order in the array has to be the same used in the CLI. So if the idea is to run this:

```
node app.js remove --id="123456789"
```

The `launch.json` object should look like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [       
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Test Remove",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
      "args": [
        "remove",
        "--id=123456789"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Changing the order inside the `args` array will result in an unwanted behavior.